# Azure Web App - No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'OpenIdConnect'

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

We have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app that utilizes multiple authentication schemes to support API and customer logins. The specific code to handle this is below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "smart";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "smart";
})
.AddToken<TokenAuthenticationService>(options =>
{
    options.TokenFieldName = "Token";
}).AddPolicyScheme("smart", "Bearer or OpenIDConnect", options =>
{
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
    {
        string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (authHeader?.StartsWith("Bearer ") == true)
        {
            return TokenAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }
        return OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    };
});
```

A customer uses the classic version of the Azure App Service built-in authentication and authorization capability ("Easy Auth"). Recently, we provided an update to our ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app hosted in the App Service. The web app has changed slightly in functionality; however, the version of Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI NuGet package is quite different. The original web app references the 0.4.0-preview version of Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI NuGet package and the updated web app references the 2.15.3 version of Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI NuGet package. When deployed to the App Service, that change resulted in the following exception: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'OpenIdConnect.'

I've tracked down the cause of the exception to a change introduced in version 1.2.0 of Microsoft.Identity.Web. Specifically, from the GitHub wiki: Note that when Microsoft.Identity.Web detects EasyAuth,it automatically overrides the default authentication scheme to be AppServicesAuthenticationDefaults.AppServicesAuthenticationDefaults, and uses this scheme instead of the OpenIdConnect scheme.

My question is, what can I do to resolve this incompatibility? I attempted to recreate the issue in my Azure development instance; however, I cannot create an App Service that utilizes the legacy version of Easy Auth. Is there a workaround that would allow me to do that? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To revert to Easy Auth version 1.0, use the following Azure CLI command:

```
 az webapp auth config-version revert
```

After the conversion, any additional configuration changes required to match the previous environment can be configured with the Azure Resource Explorer.

[Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/)